# Фильтрация связанной модели django

Tags: django, django-model

Есть две модели

```
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField("Сессия", max_length=256, null=True)
class Chat(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, verbose_name="Пользователи", null=True)
```

Мы можем вывести все чаты пользователя 1, также мы выводим всех пользователей для каждого чата. Необходимо при помощи функции отфильтровать пользователей чата, чтобы не выводился пользователь с id 1

```
chats = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=1).chat_set
```

Comment: в чем проблема? .exclude есть же

Answer (score 2):

`profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=1)`  # вы должны понимать, что тут может вернуться 404

`chats = profile.chat_set.exclude(users_pk__in=[1])`  # [тут можете перечислить ID которые хотите игнорировать]